# При загрузке страницы скрипт ведет себя по-разному

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть скрипт, который должен имитировать `background-size: cover` при работе с img в произвольном блоке. Скрипт высчитывает соотношение сторон блока-обертки и самого изображения, сравнивает их и, в зависимости от результата, наделяет картинку css-свойствами. Если картинка "горизонтальней" блока, она заполняет его по высоте, а если "вертикальней" - по ширине.

Скрипт:

```
function flexImage() {

    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

        $(args[i]).each(function() {

            let wrapper = $(this),
                image = $(this).find('img');

            if ( (image.height() / image.width()) < (wrapper.height() / wrapper.width()) ) {
                image.css({
                    "height":"100%",
                    "width":"auto",
                    "max-width":"inherit",
                });
            } else {
                image.css({
                    "height":"auto",
                    "width":"100%",
                    "max-width":"100%",
                });
            }
        });

    }
}

$(window).on('load', function() {
    flexImage('.post-mini > article', '.slider-thumbnail', 'article.review .post-thumbnail');   
});
```

Проблема в том, что скрипт по-разному работает при обновлении страницы и при переходе на нее с другой. Если обновить страницу, изображения ведут себя так, как задумывалось. Если же перейти на страницу, скажем, по ссылке в меню, то некоторые изображения (всегда одни и те же) отображаются неправильно. Причем, скрипт все равно отрабатывает, но дает им не те свойства, как если бы они были с другими `height`/`width`. Это происходит вот на [этой странице](https://osanna-spa.in.ua/blog/). Если перейти туда по ссылке, то можно увидеть, как около картинок в миниатюрах остаются пустые пробелы. Но если страницу обновить, они пропадут.

Еще интересней [здесь](https://osanna-spa.in.ua/) - в блоке "отзывы" миниатюры при обновлении страницы отображаются по-разному. Одна аватарка при обновлении поочередно принимает то одни, то другие свойства из скрипта. Вторая ведет себя стабильней, но иногда тоже дает сбой.

Кстати, скрипт тестировался на локальном сервере и вел себя как порядочный js. А вот при запуске в "живом" интернете происходит вот такое.

upd: исправил код в соответствии с подсказкой Perfecto Web, однако проблема осталась.

upd 2: проблема была в pagespeed. Вопрос решен

Comment: Вытащите `$(window).on('load', function() {` из цикла, и никогда такого не делайте.  :) Поставьте его до выполнения скрипта, если хотите, чтобы скрипт запустился после загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Вытащите **`$(window).on('load', function() {`** из цикла, и никогда такого не делайте. :) Поставьте его до выполнения скрипта, если хотите, чтобы скрипт запустился после загрузки страницы.

```js
function flexImage() {

    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            $(args[i]).each(function() {

                let wrapper = $(this),
                    image = $(this).find('img');

                if ( (image.height() / image.width()) < (wrapper.height() / wrapper.width()) ) {
                    image.css({
                        "height":"100%",
                        "width":"auto",
                        "max-width":"inherit",
                    });
                } else {
                    image.css({
                        "height":"auto",
                        "width":"100%",
                        "max-width":"100%",
                    });
                }
            });

    }
}


$(window).on('load', function() {
    flexImage();
});
```

Comment: Исправил код, теперь `$(window).on('load' ...` вынесен отдельно, однако проблема осталась.
Причем, на локальном сервере все работает идеально.

Comment: посмотрел в хроме и по ссылке, и после релоада - никакой разницы.

А если онлоад навесить не на `window`, а на `document`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обертку $(window).on('load', function() {}) убрать, а скрипт подключить так:

```
<script src="script .js" defer></script>
```